# Is there a more efficient way to show DOM element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to implement a simple menu just by using Vanilla JS. So I have a working onclick function, where I just twist visibility property on click of the menu item. CSS is by default set on `visibility:hidden`

```js
function getContentP() {

  var div = document.getElementById("menu1Content");

  if (div.style.visibility === "hidden") {

    div.style.visibility = "visible";

  } else {
    div.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
};
```

```html
<a href="#menu1" onclick="getContentP()">
  <h2>title</h2>
</a>

<!-- CONTENT BOX, show on clicks-->
<div id="menu1Content" style="background: #fefefe">
  Some content to make it visible
</div>
```

This works as expected, but really slowly, and with poor results.
Any good suggestion to improve the code? And maybe add some nice transitions like fadeIn effect without using jQuery?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You don't need `class="hidden"` in your markup if you toggle styles.

Comment: Have you tried a different web browser?

Comment: "but really slowly" — When I try the code it is close enough to instantaneous that it might as well be. What environment are you finding it slow in?

Comment: Why has it poor performance? It should be lightning fast, like microseconds to toggle visibility.

Comment: I tested on latest versions of Chrome, FF and Edge. I usually need two clicks on the link to get it to show in the first place, which is really strange. Also it takes .7s to show the element on the first iteration, and than after that it is more-less instant.

Comment: That's because you don't cancel the default event, which is to navigate to the anchor. Replace the <a> tag with a <p> or <div> or cancel the default event (google it up, it's a one-liner) to get the desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [from comments] I usually need two clicks on the link to get it to show in the first place, which is really strange

No, that is anything but strange.

`element.style.property` only allows you to access CSS values that where set either directly via a `style` attribute on the element, or by assigning a value to `element.style.property` via script.

Both is not the case here, and your `class="hidden"` that you had in your code initially (before editing it out) was likely to set the element’s visibility hidden from the stylesheet, right?

Therefor, when you check the current visibility of the element here for the first time,

```
if (div.style.visibility === "hidden") {
```

that condition is not true, so you set the visibility to hidden in your else-branch – and therefor the element *stays* hidden.

Now, on your second click, the value `hidden` *was* set via script, so now you can read it back. Now that if condition results in true, and your script sets the element to `visible`.

Easy way to work around this – turn the logic around:

Check `div.style.visibility === "visible"`, and set the element to `hidden` if that’s true, and `visible` if it is false.

The element is hidden (via the stylesheet) when your page first loads. Because of what I explained before, `div.style.visibility` can’t read the value on the first click, so the condition will be false, and the element will be made visible.

Answer (score 2):

Im not sure what slowly means in this case or what poor results you are seeing, but in general the thing that jumps out at me is the usage of onclick. When passing code like that to a dom element the runtime will essentially `eval` the snippet which is bad for a number of reasons, and certainly not great for performance (also likely can never be optimized by the vm).

`element.addEventListener('click', function() { 'your stuff here' }, false);`
may give you better performance but id be shocked if you can even tell the difference unless this is called thousands or maybe millions of times.

You could also cache the dom element since  you seem be doing a lookup by id, then you dont have to do a potentially expensive dom search every time the thing is clicked.

I'm not css guru but you can probably get something cool with [this](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) without too much effort.

Comment: +1 for Animate.css. But one correction: as long as the source code (string) does not change there is no reason why a modern engine like V8 shouldn't cache the compilation result (native executable code) of the onlick handler. This means eval will compile the handler only once as long as it does not change.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML (note the added `id`):

```
<a href="#" id="menu1Toggle" style="visibility: hidden;">
  <h2>title</h2>
</a>
```

The handler (note the added `ev` and `preventDefault()`):

```
function getContentP(ev)
{
  var div = document.getElementById("menu1Content");

  div.style.visibility = div.style.visibility === "hidden" ? "visible" : "hidden";
  ev.preventDefault();
};
```

Attach the event with:

```
document.getElementById("menu1Toggle").onclick = getContentP;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use opacity if you want to fadeIn/Out. Just add a CSS transition. An easy toggle method would be:

```
elem.style.opacity = +!parseInt(elem.style.opacity);
```

Not sure if this would perform better/worse, but [here is a Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jp4b4sbL/1/)

Comment: That's not [cross-browser compatible](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/opacity.html).

Comment: @pid - Right. God speed to those still supporting lte IE8.

Comment: Intresting code, how does that work then ? plus do not parseInt?

Comment: The `parseInt` is there because the opacity value could be a string. The `!` gives an inverse boolean from the opacity value. The `+` parses the boolean as an integer.

Comment: @pid, `opacity` has [as much support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-opacity) among browsers currently in use as does `a:hover` and `min-width`. If you wouldn't consider that "cross-browser compatible," nothing is!

Comment: @daGUY Yes and no. It depends on the context. For administrative websites you must adhere to guidelines for accessibility. 1% of userbase means a browser must be supported, thus cross-browser compatibility is very strict. For corporate websites you may do as you wish.